# Images are failed to render on the webpage

Tags: html

Trying out a simple table in HTML with images and hyperlinks. Images are in a different folder than the source code of HTML and CSS files.

Tried Mozilla MDN reference to verify my syntax of the image source.

what is wrong in the syntax? Should I make some difference while importing images from the different folder?

bhddua_mudra.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Buddha Mudra</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table border=1>
    <thead>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Reference</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="fit-picture" src="/Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/abhayamudra.JPG" alt="Abhayam Mudra" />
        </td>
        <td>Abhayam Mudra</td>
        <td><a href="https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abhayamudra"> Abhayam Mudra</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="fit-picture" src="/Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/bhumisparsa.JPG" alt="Bhumisparsa Mudra" />
        </td>
        <td>Bhumisparsa Mudra</td>
        <td><a href="https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mudra"> Bhumisparsa Mudra</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="fit-picture" src="/Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/dharmachakra.JPG" alt="Dharmachakra Mudra" />
        </td>
        <td>Dharmachakra Mudra</td>
        <td><a href="https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mudra"> Abhayam Mudra</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="fit-picture" src="/Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/dhyanmudra.JPG" alt="Dhyan Mudra" />
        </td>
        <td>Dhyan Mudra</td>
        <td><a href="https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mudra"> Dhyan Mudra</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="fit-picture" src="/Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/karanmudra.JPG" alt="Karan Mudra" />
        </td>
        <td>Karan Mudra</td>
        <td><a href="https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abhayamudra/Mudra">Karan Mudra</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="fit-picture" src="/Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/veradamudra.JPG" alt="Verada Mudra" />
        </td>
        <td>Verada Mudra</td>
        <td><a href="https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abhayamudra/Mudra">Verada Mudra</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="fit-picture" src="/Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/vitarkamudra.JPG" alt="Vitarka Mudra" />
        </td>
        <td>Vitarka Mudra</td>
        <td><a href="https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abhayamudra/Mudra">Vitarka Mudra</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

**DIRECTORY STRUCTURE**

```
HTML
  -dist
        -img
        (all images here)

  -mozilla 
    (HTML and CSS here)
```

Comment: Please check the correct path of image and add in src

Comment: Hi, checked but no success! :(

Comment: please tell your html file location and images path also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below mentioned points I think this may resolve your issue.

1. Please add correct Absolute or relative path to your image src.
2. After adding from developer console try to open that image in different tab
3. Third but important point is check you file permission for image and it's folder and if it is not 755 please change it.

I think this might work for you.

Comment: Is there permission issue ?

Comment: no, but file was not able to render through localhost. When I opend it through file location it worked(after putting this path: `src="file:///Users/kuldeep/PycharmProjects/HTML/src/img/dhyanmudra.JPG"`

Answer (score 0):

If your html folder and img folder location is different then you will give the full pc location.
Suppose that your image location is in images folder of d: drive and your html is in desktop or anywhere in the pc:
Here i have image in desktop images folder.Then img tag should look like this.

```
<img src=”D:/images/sun.jpg” alt=”Sun”></img>
```

Comment: in which directories image are you using?

Comment: added my directory structure for clarification.